# Google Analytics API is returning no data. But dashboard is showing data for user events

Tags: laravel, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-4

I have mobile applications that consistently send event logs to Firebase, with Google Analytics enabled for this project on Firebase. The user event data is visible on both the Firebase Dashboard and Google Analytics Dashboard, functioning as intended.

Recently, I integrated the GA 4 API with my Laravel application. When I make a request using Postman, the API returns an empty object **{}** with an HTTP status code of **200**. The requests are successfully recorded in Google Cloud Platform (GCP), and the API count on GCP is updated accordingly.

However, I am encountering an issue where I consistently receive the same record as mentioned above, even when specifying the minimum required fields for confirming the API's functionality. I have referred to the documentation for checking the client library, but the API does not seem to be functioning as expected, even with the minimum specified fields. Your assistance in resolving this matter is highly appreciated.

This is code I am testing in Laravel for fetching the records:

```
`<?php

namespace App\Classes;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DimensionExpression;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DimensionExpression\ConcatenateExpression;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\FilterExpression;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Compatibility;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\NumericFilter\Operation;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\NumericFilter;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DimensionValue;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\NumericValue;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\StringFilter;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\StringFilter\MatchType;


class TestingCode
{


    function __construct()
    {
    }

    static function checkAPI()
    {
        $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

        $response = $client->runReport([
            'property' => 'properties/{Property_ID}',
            "returnPropertyQuota" => true,
            'dimensions' => [
                new Dimension(
                    [
                        'name' => 'Country',
                    
                    ]
                ),
            ],
            'metrics' => [
                new Metric(
                    [
                        'name' => 'active7DayUsers',
                    ]
                )
            ],
            'dateRanges' => [
                new DateRange([
                    'start_date' => '2024-01-01',
                    'end_date' => 'today',
                ]),
            ],
        ]);
        return response()->json($response);
    }
}`
```